# Magento Admin Order - ReOrder

Tags: magento-1.9

I've been trying to find details about the Admin - order - reorder function in Magento 1 but there seems very little if any information.
Even the Magento 1 user guide doesn't mention it!
I only want to find out the proper use of it as one of our admin staff struggled to get it to work.
Any help would be much appreciated
Thank you
Andy
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reorder button is used to create a new order with the same details as the current order has.
The customer name, billing address, ordered items everything will be fetched from the current order and you can instantly create the new order with same.

You can change any detail while creating this order if you want.

Comment: Thank you Dinesh Yadav. I understand the concept, but our admin team had an issue because the original product was in the 'shopping cart' and when they tried to create the reorder they said they ended up with two items in the shopping cart. They needed to amend the product price. I just wanted to read the official documentation on how exactly the function should be used, but i'm struggling to find anything. - Thanks Andy